# Javascript - Download prompting of self created batch files

Tags: javascript, batch-processing, client-side, client-side-scripting

I"m a noob in `javascript` so I am sorry if my question is a simple one. anyway, 
I'm writing a code that creates a batch file in order to open a certain file in the default application defined by the operation system. For example, pdf files will open in Adobe's Acrobat Reader. To do so, I'm using the [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

And my code goes like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#openPdf').click(function() {
        saveAs(data2blob(
                myPDF), 
            'openPDF.bat');
    });
});

function data2blob(data, isBase64) {
    var chars = "";
    if (isBase64)
        chars = atob(data);
    else
        chars = data;

    var bytes = new Array(chars.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
        bytes[i] = chars.charCodeAt(i);
    var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(bytes)], 
            {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    return blob;
}
```

with `myPDF` being a string to a specific file I want to open which I'm certain of its existence. When I test my code on IE, it works perfectly. However, when I try it on Firefox, the file created is 'openPDF.bat.sdx' instead of 'openPDF.bat'. I've checked that it is indeed the same file only with the added extension. Does anyone have an idea what is the reason for this? and how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to download the file in Firefox the same way as in IE. I've made one minor change in the code: when creating the `blob` variable in the `data2blob` function I've used:

```
var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(bytes)], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
```

Not sure, what is the difference between the way it was before and how it is now, except of the result of course.